# IE adding Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded to GET requests

Tags: internet-explorer, get, content-type

I have a web application, which has references to CSS and JS files, as below:

When the site is loaded in IE by some users, browser tries to issue a:
GET /ifastweb_sp/vendor/angular-hotkeys-master/hotkeys.css HTTP/1.1
but with "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in request header.

This is incorrect, as GET is not supposed to have content-type. Has anybody seen this behavior? Why would IE send this, and how to stop this from happening?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue - also with angular. Are you using AngularJS or Angular 2/4?

Comment: We are using Angular 1.5

Comment: I'm using Angular 1.6. I'm also using AWS S3 for file hosting, and Azure ADFS for authentication. Is any of that similar to your situation?

Comment: We are hosting internally, within our datacenter. We do have an SSO integration for our clients, and that flow is where this issue pops up.

Comment: We've noticed that on ours if you're already logged in (office365 for example) then the issue doesn't occur.